# My android button is not working

Tags: android, button, exit

I have 2 activity and 2 file .xml, in nameActivity have buttonCancel and buttonNewUser, in SignUpActivity have buttonBack, when I'm click buttonNewUser it's execute SignUpActivity, when I'm click buttonBack it's back to nameActivity but when I'm click buttonCancel it's back to SignUpActivity, it's like just walk in circles.

Code in nameActivity like this:

```
Button signUp, cancel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    signUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNewUser);
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });

    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

code in SignUpActivity :

Button back;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBackSignUp);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),NameActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

why, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `SignUpActivity` to use finish the activity instead of starting the original one again, because right now you are just creating a new instance of `NameActivity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBackSignUp);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, do not use `System.exit()`. While used in Java, you need not do this in Android development.